# Como fazer um gráfico condicional y~x para cada fator do data.frame?

Tags: r, data.frame, plot, gráfico-de-dispersão, gráfico-condicional

Suponha um data.frame como o seguinte:

```
set.seed(1)
dados <- data.frame(w=rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 50), y= rnorm(200), x=rnorm(200),
                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Como criar um gráfico `y~x` separado por cada categoria de `w`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode também usar a biblioteca lattice para isso.

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(y~x|w, data=dados)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 7):

Uma maneira é usar a função `coplot`:

```
coplot(y~x |w, data=dados)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Também é possível fazer com o `ggplot2` usando `facet_wrap`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=dados, aes(y=y, x=x))+ geom_point(aes(color=w))+facet_wrap( ~ w)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito bom! Me ajuntou pra caramba